# Object browser not working for c++ in VS 2015 community

Tags: c++, visual-studio, documentation, objectbrowser

For some reason I just can't get the Object browser to pick up my function/class documentation in Visual Studio 2015 Community.

I have tried as described here [XML Documentation (Visual C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177226.aspx).

The functions appear in the Object browser, but none of the documentation.
For example,

```
/// <summary>Executes the TSQL-statement on the current DB connection.</summary>
/// <param name="query">The TSQL-statement to execute.</param>
void executeSqlStmt(const std::string& query);
```

This shows up in the Object Browser as

[image: Screenshot from Object Browser]

Am I missing some configuration? I have set the generate documentation setting to "No", because currently I am not interested in generating .xml files, but only to view the function documentation in the IDE as Intellisense help.

Thank you.

Comment: I have also never been able to make it work. If you call you function and write `(`, you will notice, that function and arguments description will be displayed properly. But Object Browser simply refuses to parse/collect/save/whatever XML doc comments. I observed this for the first time in VS2010, it seems, that it is still not fixed...

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek I agree with your observations, I get the same thing.